# How do I execute an If statement inside a CTE

Tags: t-sql, ssrs-2012

I need to create a cte based on the value of an SSRS report parameter.  The If statement in the attached code executes just fine outside the cte, but errors inside the cte.

I and one of my coworkers have spent several hours unsuccessfully trying to solve this.  I have tried using a CASE statement.  I have tried placing the WITH cteIngnoreCommID AS inside both the IF and ELSE, but nothing works.
This cte will be joined in subsequent code that creates another cte.  Hopefully someone can tell me what I need to do.

```
--Declare and set Report parameter for testing purposes only
Declare @IgnoreYear as varchar(4)='2010'
;
WITH cteIgnoreCommID as (
    IF @IgnoreYear=''
        -- create cte with one record have blank values
        Select '' as IgnoreComm_ID
            ,'' as IgnoreYear
            ,0 as IngnoreBalFwd
    ELSE 
        -- create cte with records obtained from multiple tables.
        -- for proof of concept I am just creating one record.
        Select '30710000' as IgnoreComm_ID
            ,@IgnoreYear as IgnoreYear
            ,5000 as IngnoreBalFwd
                        )
--The above code run just fine if you comment out the cte lines.
```

I get the correct results if run the IF/ELSE outside the cte.  When run as written with the cte I get the following 2 errors:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'IF'. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 13 Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use `CASE` statements inside the CTE. You could modify your CTE to look like this and it should do what you want:

```
Declare @IgnoreYear as varchar(4)='2010'
;
WITH cteIgnoreCommID as (
        Select CASE WHEN @IgnoreYear='' THEN '' 
                ELSE '30710000' 
                END AS IgnoreComm_ID
            ,CASE WHEN @IgnoreYear='' THEN '' 
                ELSE @IgnoreYear
                END as IgnoreYear
            ,CASE WHEN @IgnoreYear='' THEN 0 
                ELSE 5000
                END as IngnoreBalFwd
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the `if` outside the CTE and make the CTE declaration based on the conditional instead:

```
if 3 > 2

BEGIN 
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT 1 AS val
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte 
END 

ELSE 

BEGIN 
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT 2 AS val
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte 
END
```

Using your code:

```
Declare @IgnoreYear as varchar(4)='2010'
IF @IgnoreYear=''

BEGIN 
;WITH cteIgnoreCommID AS (
-- create cte with one record have blank values
        Select '' as IgnoreComm_ID
            ,'' as IgnoreYear
            ,0 as IngnoreBalFwd
)
SELECT * 
FROM cteIgnoreCommID
END

ELSE 

BEGIN 
;WITH cteIgnoreCommID AS (
Select '30710000' as IgnoreComm_ID
            ,@IgnoreYear as IgnoreYear
            ,5000 as IngnoreBalFwd
)

SELECT * 
FROM cteIgnoreCommID
END
```

Comment: Of the 3 responses I have received, this comes the closest to working.  This does create the same CTE with different data based on the value of @IgnoreYear.  However, once this CTE is generated I need to join it with 3 other CTE's.  So for this to work, I would have to repeat the same code between the 2 BEGIN / END which makes modification much harder.

Comment: @MickB Or insert the results into a temp table if having the result set persist is a hurdle you have to overcome.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
Declare @IgnoreYear as varchar(4)='2010'
;
WITH cteIgnoreCommID as (
        -- create cte with one record have blank values
        Select '' as IgnoreComm_ID
            ,'' as IgnoreYear
            ,0 as IngnoreBalFwd WHERE @IgnoreYear = ''
        UNION ALL
        -- create cte with records obtained from multiple tables.
        -- for proof of concept I am just creating one record.
        Select '30710000' as IgnoreComm_ID
            ,@IgnoreYear as IgnoreYear
            ,5000 as IngnoreBalFwd WHERE (@IgnoreYear IS NULL OR @IgnoreYear <> '')
                        )
SELECT * 
FROM cteIgnoreCommID
```

If @IgnoreYear is never NULL, then you can remove the "@IgnoreYear IS NULL OR" part.

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly new to SQL but the answer to my problem ended up being to not create a CTE but a Temp Table.  This handled my IF statement fine and I could join to it with the data as required by the report parameter.  The code I used to create either a blank temp table or a filled temp table was:

```
create table #tmpIgnoreComm
    ( IgnoreComm_ID varchar(8)
     ,IgnoreYear varchar(4)
     ,IngnoreBalFwd numeric  )
If @IgnoreYear<>''
    insert into #tmpIgnoreComm
        --(IgnoreComm_ID,IgnoreYear,IngnoreBalFwd)
    Select * 
    From 
    (   Select Distinct
        -- Long code to retrieve data
    ) data
```

Thanks everyone for you input.